# how to clear heap memory of eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My eclipse is showing heap memory full error, it automatically restarts. Please suggest a way to clean Heap memory of eclipse. I'm using indigo eclipse

I have cleaned the project but it does not help

Comment: Did you already increase the heapsize that is available for eclipse? See http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Answer (score 23):

Within `Eclipse.ini`, you can configure heap settings.

This [blog](http://blog.xam.dk/?p=58) throws more light on it.

Through UI you can try in following way:

- Enable `Show heap status` under Window -> Preferences -> General. (turned off by default).
- Simply check this box to display a heap size indicator on the lower right corner. This indicator displays the maximum JVM heap size and how much of it is being used.
- Another useful feature of this indicator is the ability to garbage collect the heap.

Comment: "Another useful feature of this indicator is the ability to garbage collect the heap." - Though that won't help if the heap is full.  The JVM runs the GC when it needs to.  A "heap full + restart" scenario means that the JVM was still out of / nearly out of memory *after* the GC had just run.

Comment: A cynical take on the GC button is that it is a way to distract C / C++ programmers complaining about Eclipse sluggishness :-)

Answer (score 11):

Check `Preferences > General > Show heap status`. Then click on the trash icon at the bottom part of the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that your real problem is that Eclipse itself is running out of memory.  If this is the case, then "clearing" the heap won't actually help.

There are a couple of approaches that can help to fix the problem:

- You can reduce Eclipse's memory usage by closing projects, getting rid of unnecessary plugins and so on.  However, this tends to reduce Eclipse's usefulness.
- You can change the JVM -Xmx and -Xms settings in the "eclipse.ini" file to give Eclipse a larger heap.  But this only works if you have enough RAM and you stay under the address space limits imposed by your OS and the hardware<sup>1</sup>.
- If neither of the above solves the problem, you need a machine with more memory.

<sup>1 - A 32 bit OS and hardware will limit you to around 2Gb of usable heap space ... though the limit varies a bit depending on various factors.  It is all to do with the way that the OS manages processes virtual address spaces.  But you need to be developing a pretty big system in Eclipse for this to be a real concern.</sup>

---

Note that "Show heap status" and clicking the trash can icon won't solve the problem.  The JVM running Eclipse will always do a full garbage collection before it bails out with an `OutOfMemoryError`.  (This functionality is not entirely useless though.  Forcing a garbage collection can make Eclipse more responsive for a bit ... once the GC has completed.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `xms` and `xmx` arguments in the `RunConfigurations` of your class'  vm arguments. 
using `Run`-> `Run Configurations` -> `Arguments tab`

if your application is large and lots of object created you can change size of heap space by using JVM options `-Xms` and `-Xmx`.  Xms denotes starting size of Heap while -Xmx denotes maximum size of Heap in Java.